# Find if a string is in a json file, then get the stuff around it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, discord.js

So I don't know a lot about JSON, I'm making a bot for a game that you can message and it sends you a code that you then send to my discord bot to link your account. I'm doing this by making it so whenever the bot is friended in game it accepts the request and sends a message to the user with a 5 Character code that is randomly generated and then stored in users.json with their player ID and Displayname. I'm done with the bot part mostly just the discord part now, I need to find if the code they input is in the json file and then get the displayName that goes with that code. If that makes sense...

Here's users.json with only one entry:

```
{"users":[{"name":"ImBattleDash","Id":"34a02cf8f4414e29b15921876da36f9a","code":"5MJS3"}]}
```

and here's the code to add to it:

```
        fs.readFile('./users.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err

        var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data)
        arrayOfObjects.users.push({
            name: userAuthorName,
            Id: userAuthor,
            code: authorCode
        })

        console.log(arrayOfObjects)

        fs.writeFile('./users.json', JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects), 'utf-8', function(err) {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('Done!')
        })
```

What I basically need is to search in the Json file for example if one of the codes is "5MZJ2" and if it is then get the name that goes with that and set it to a variable.

I've been trying to figure out how to do it but I'm still quite a beginner so some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please can you elaborate your requirement?

Comment: Basically I just need to search through a Json file to see if "code" is a certain string in any part of the file and then get "name" for where that "code" is. Sorry if it doesn't make sense

Comment: Create model class (.js or .ts) same as json and covert json to model class or component. Search code through that class or component. use this link you can understand how to create class or component as json.https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Create users .js or .ts class and add name,id,code as variables

Comment: well I don't think that would work because for every user that is made a new entry needs to be made, there can't be multiple variables with the same name and I don't want to create an entirely new variable for every user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to do it is to use the [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, a solution would be:

```
let myCode = "5MJS3"
fs.readFile('./users.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err

    var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data)
    let myEntry = arrayOfObjects.users.find(entry => entry.code == myCode)

    console.log(myEntry.name)
})
```

It basically go through your list and looks for an entry mathing the code :)

Comment: @BattleDash Please mark this answer as the `solution/best answer` - so others can also recognize it as best answer.

Comment: Right sorry forgot